# JavaScript setInterval: function not defined

Tags: javascript, html, css

What is wrong with this code? I am getting an error that says, "Uncaught ReferenceError: displayTime is not defined"

```js
document.getElementById('btn-2').addEventListener('click', function displayTime() {
  if (time_area.style.display == 'none') {
    time_area.style.display = 'inline-block';
    document.getElementById('btn-2-time').innerHTML = 'Hide Time ';
    document.getElementById('time_area').innerHTML = new Date();
  } else {
    time_area.style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('btn-2-time').innerHTML = 'Show Time';
  }
});

setInterval(displayTime, 1000);
```

Comment: You don't have `displayTime` is not visible at all. It's only inline.

Comment: take out displayTime method from the click event handler so that it will be visible to setInterval method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`displayTime` is passed as an inline function to the event listener handler. It doesn't exist in the scope where you call `setInterval`. You need to pull it out so you can reference it outside of that closure:

```js
function displayTime() {
  if (time_area.style.display == 'none') {
    time_area.style.display = 'inline-block';
    document.getElementById('btn-2-time').innerHTML = 'Hide Time ';
    document.getElementById('time_area').innerHTML = new Date();
  } else {
    time_area.style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('btn-2-time').innerHTML = 'Show Time';
  }
}

document.getElementById('btn-2').addEventListener('click', displayTime);
        
setInterval(displayTime, 1000);
```